# C++: assignment operator not called

Tags: c++, overloading, variable-assignment

I have a following code which is below.

When I write `o1 = o2`, `void operator=(TestClass& _rhs)` is called. It's ok.

But when I do `o1 = test_function();`, first `operator float()` is called, then `void operator=(float _value)`. It's logically correct, but why is `void operator=(TestClass& _rhs)` not invoked?

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(float _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    operator float()
    {
        return value;
    }

    void operator=(float _value)
    {
    }

    void operator=(TestClass& _rhs)
    {
    }

private:
    float value;
};

TestClass test_function()
{
    TestClass result = 0;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

    TestClass o1(1), o2(1);

    o1 = o2;

    o1 = test_function();
}
```

Comment: Looks like copy elision to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: You're overcomplicating this: `void foo(int& i); foo(get_int());`

Comment: Try making assignment operator argument const? `void operator=(const TestClass& rhs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why void operator=(TestClass& _rhs) is not involved?

Because that assignment operator is malformed.  It should be:

```
void operator=(TestClass const& _rhs)
//                CONST! ^^^^^
```

Your form, `void operator=(TestClass& _rhs)` will not accept prvalues (temporaries), like the temporary returned from `test_function()`.

So, the only **valid** assignment in your code is `void operator=(float _value)`, which is possible because your class can implicitly convert to a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare operator= differently for TestClass. Either use

```
void operator=(const TestClass& _rhs)
```

or

```
void operator=(TestClass _rhs)
```

This is because function test_functions returns a temporary value, and you cannot bind temporarily to a non-const lvalue reference. This is why the other operator=(float) is selected.

You may find overload resolution rules here: https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/8117/steps-of-overload-resolution